# auto escaping additional characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on page http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/ if you are to hover over a member, you will notice "What I\\'m about!:"

I've looked high and low through the .js files and .php for this plugin (BP Avatar Bubble) with no indication of what is causing this to redundantly escape the apostrophe.  IF anyone could point me in the right direction for what to look for, all I'm after.. I tried ssh find'ing a few different ideas I had to identify it and I looked through all files manually.

On the admin side it does this as well:

Check here all fields from users profiles you want to show in a bubble:
What I\'m about! → textarea

With a single \, so I think ajax side is doing this and then its refering back to whatever is declared on the admin side to where it is appending an extra two \ again.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Too much php to paste, here is the 3 files named as a txt

http://www.thefruitnation.com/debug/php_for_avatar_bubble_3_files.txt

Comment: You need to post some code. We can't see your PHP code from here. Most likely, you're using `addslashes` inappropriately in your PHP code.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should paste that much, so I added as a link to a txt.  I didn't add any code originally because I had no indication where the issue is arising.. I searched for addslashes and magic quotes to see if anything was wrong, didn't identify anything

Comment: Can you whittle it down to a small test case? You don't really expect anyone to scan through 1200 lines of your code looking for your bug?

Comment: Well, no I don't expect anyone.  I'm still persistently researching it myself as well. I checked the db and it shows the value in the table with the apostrophe escaped.  I think it has to do with how Buddypress uses addslashes and some other escape functions.  I will check with someone more familiar directly with buddypress on the support site.

Comment: you can use htmlspecialchars() function to encode and while display you can use htmlspecialchars_decode() if you don't have search functionality on the text column